# Generating multiple ndjson files [3000+] by filtering the pandas dataframe for difference criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concurrent.futures

I need to generate 3000+ ndjson files from a pandas data frame based on certain criteria. I tried running the following code, it works but it takes a lot of time to finish.

```
def p_generate_files(result_df: pd.DataFrame, p_code: str) -> None:
    print(result_df.shape)
    tmp_df = result_df.filter(like=str(p_code), axis=0)
    start_date = tmp_df.index.unique(level='date').min().to_pydatetime().strftime('%b').upper()
    end_date = tmp_df.index.unique(level='date').max().to_pydatetime().strftime('%b').upper()
    file_name_path = f'data/CR-{p_code}-{start_date}-{end_date}-2000.json'
    tmp_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    tmp_df.to_json(
            file_name_path,
            orient="records",
            index=True,
            lines=True)
    result_df.drop(labels= p_code, inplace = True)
```

I tried the following implementation of parallel processing but it doesn't seem to work. I have no experience with concurrent programming. Any help to speed up the processing is appreciated.

```
p_generate_files = partial(generate_files,result_df=big_df)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(p_generate_files, p_codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `multiprocessing`, you have to set up the inputs as a list of tuples

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def generate_files(result_df: pd.DataFrame, codes: list) -> None:
    # Your function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cores = mp.cpu_count()
    args = [(df1, lst1), (df2, lst2), (df3, lst3) ...]

    with mp.Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(merge_names, args)
```

Comment: ```result_df``` is one consolidated dataframe from which I need to generate multiple ndjson files based on the pcode.

Comment: the `results` variable will be a list of dataframes that you can use to create your ndjson